# Given the null-space of a matrix, can we calculate the generating matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

If I have a matrix

```
A = [1 0 0]
```

Then

```
null(A)

ans =

     0     0
     1     0
     0     1
```

Is there a way I can get A from `null(A)`? Or in other words: given the null-space of a matrix, is it possible to find out which matrix that null-space belongs to?

Comment: AFAIK, this has infinite solutions

Comment: In your example, [b 0 0] would have the same null space as A, as long as b is not 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.

Every matrix has a single, unique [null-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)), but for any given null-space, there are infinitely many matrices that would generate it. In more mathematical terms: calculating a null-space from a matrix is a many-to-one operation, thus reversing the operation would be one-to-many.
So no, there isn't a way to obtain a specific, unique matrix generating a given null-space without any other constraints.